# Validating a single prop when you have mulitple

Tags: javascript, validation, vuejs2, vue.js

How do you validate a single prop in Vue when you have multiple props?

I currently have this:

```
export default {
    props: {
        src: { required: true },
        alt: { required: false }
    },

    data() {
        return {

        };
    }
};
```

But I do not need any validation for my `alt` prop. Normally if I would not need validation I would just use an array but am I forced to now do validation for my `alt` in the form of `required: false` as well now?

Comment: just keep the alt blank, like `alt:{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `alt: null` if you want to allow `alt` to be anything or nothing but chances are you want that to be a string or nothing so you likely want:

```
props: {
  src: {
    required: true,
  },
  alt: String,
},
```